# Android - Way to pass data without intent

Tags: android, android-intent

If I got the value 30
instead of writing

Activity 1:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, Activity2);
i.putExtras("number", 30);
```

Activity 2:

```
Intent i = getIntent();
int number = i.getStringExtras("number");
i.putExtras("number", 30);
i = new Intent(this, Activity3);
```

Activity 3:

```
Intent i = getIntent();
int number = i.getStringExtras("number");
i.putExtras("number", 30);
i = new Intent(this, Activity4);
```

and so on, you get the idea. The reason being is a need certain values to be passed to Activity 1 then when Activity 1 is done, move to Activity 2 with those values.

is there some kind of Universal Intent store I can call?

Comment: Why not use `SharedPreference` rather passing the same value in almost of your activity? You can also use static variables (although it is problematic when not handled properly).

Comment: If you want the value to maintain even after the app closed, use SharedPreference. If you just need it to maintain the value while the app is opened, then a static value will do.

Answer (score 0):

Use SharedPreference will good at this case:

Save data

```
SharedPreferences pre = getSharedPreferences("share_preference_file_name", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor edit=pre.edit();
edit.putInt("number", 30);
edit.commit();

Intent i1 = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
startActivity(i1);
```

Get data at ActivityN after onCreate()

```
SharedPreferences pre = getSharedPreferences("share_preference_file_name", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor edit=pre.edit();
edit.getInt("number", 0); // 0 is a default number if no value on given key
```